# Can't use import modules in main.js on Vue Framework

Tags: vue.js, authentication

Can't install package in Vue App

I wanna use package vue-tel-input https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input for my login form Vue but when i import and install global component I got this error:

```
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".
```

This the import code

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueTelInput from 'vue-tel-input';

Vue.use(VueTelInput);

Vue.component('js-login', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <div class="js-login-wrap">
            <form class="js-login">
            <h2 class="js-login-heading">Login to Loket</h2>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="field_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="field_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>`,
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
})
```

My directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blnWN.png)

What should i do?

Comment: Seems to be correct. If you remove the import and the registration it works fine?

Comment: can you post the code after `Vue.use`?

Comment: Yes, when i remove it works fine @Orlandster

Comment: do you have babel transpiler set correctly?

Comment: Sure, code updated @niklaz

Comment: i am using npm install vue @niklaz

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in their docs:

'ESM for browsers (2.6+ only): intended for direct imports in modern browsers via .' [reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Terms)

So try to add `type="module"` to your main.js:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: I got this error 'Access to script at 'file:///E:/loket/assets/vue/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.' My location file in E Directory

Comment: @DavidWinalda, that is not the part of the issue's scope, but you can't  load your main.js from local machine, due to CORS policy issues. There are some workarounds to bypass CORS for browser, but don't do that, since it is not safe and not good practice for production. Rather host your main.js from some server.